# Can PromQL query metrics that some label less equal than some value?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

For example, my metric looks like this:

```
node_signal{date="0731"} 1
node_signal{date="0801"} 1.5
node_signal{date="0802"} 0
```

I'm looking for something to query like this in grafana:

```
node_signal{date <= "0801"}
```

So it returns the first and the second metric.
I have no idea is it possible to do this with promql in grafana panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is not possible. Only available operations for labels are `=`, `!=`, `=~`, `!~`.

You can try a workaround based on regex selector. For example you provided in the question you'll need query

```
node_signal{date=~"0[1-7]\d\d|0801"}
```

But this approach is not pretty: it requires new regex for every new day and those regexes while being algorithmically easy generatable, are not easy to comprehend. For example for `<=0825` you'll need `0[0-7]\d\d|08[01]\d|082[0-5]`

---

Additionally, storing dates in labels of your metrics is usually not a good idea. You are increasingly cardinality of your metric which is bad for Prometheus' performance, both computational and storage-wise.

Consider changing your approach to exposed metrics with relative time: every metric has a timestamp of scraping (unless timestampis specified for the metric while exposing) associated with it. You probably can use something like `relative_date="-1"` to show that exposed event occurred on the day before scraping.

Comment: thx for your advice! In my real case, I can use regex to filter hours instead of date, so a simple regex like `"07.*|08.*"` can solve this to get metrics exposed in 7am(0720 stands for 7:20 am) and 8am only. Anyway I agree with your solution about not using dates in labels but business is not what I can decide jajaja...